# Trigger onMouseOver when mouse pointer already is over after page load

Tags: javascript, html, image, mouseevent, rollover

I have several pages that are all very similar. They have some javascript rollover links (images are preloaded, then there is a onMouseOver event that calls an image swap function and finally, there is a onMouseOut event that restores the original image).

When the user clicks on a rollover link that points to another page that has a rollover link on the exact same position, the image on the new page would be expected to load on the "over" state. This is not the case in Chrome and Safari (IE and Firefox work as expected).

So... On page load, is there a way to check if the mouse is already hovering the image to swap it right away? Something like "OnMouseAlreadyOver"?

Thank you.

Comment: You might have better luck simply using css :hover. Just checked with a link on this site, hover is displayed on pageload without moving the mouse.

Comment: "onMouseOver event that calls an image swap function" -- welcome to 1996!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you using jQuery, it works without any problems!

http://jsfiddle.net/beuae

(not only for buttons, for [divs also](http://jsfiddle.net/beuae/1/))

Actually, jQuery is a very good framework which assures everything goes as you expect, and cross-browser. This example confirms it.

Answer (score 1):

The [W3C standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3) says

> **onmouseover** = script [CT]
>       The onmouseover event occurs when the pointing device is moved onto an element. This attribute may be used with most elements.
>
> **onmousemove** = script [CT]
>       The onmousemove event occurs when the pointing device is moved while it is over an element. This attribute may be used with most elements.

`mouseover` is fired on moving over the boundary of the object. `mousemove` happens when the mouse is already over the element.

You may need to use `onmousemove` (or even both).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to actually do the calculation based on the element position and the mouse cursor position.

```
//Get Mouse Position
document.onmousemove=getMouseCoordinates;
function getMouseCoordinates(event){
    ev = event || window.event;
    mouseX = ev.pageX;
    mouseY = ev.pageY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't without passing a variable to the other page or using cookies to track which was hovered (and that will fail over if people do change their mouse position)

In theory you could check the mouse position and the button position however there is no way to get the mouse position unless an event is triggered, so the mouse has to move and if it move the CSS :hover should get triggered.

It's a minor issue tho, I doubt most people are going to click a link, wait for the next page and then expect that link to be hovered and ready to click again (why wouldn't anyone one to keep clicking the same button unless it does different things)

From a UX point of view I wonder if webkit doesn't have the best approach here, why port the action of one page to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementFromPoint(mouseX, mouseY)` to get the element, but the only way to get the cursor's position is via an event. The problem is, the only events are clicks and mouse movements, which require user input from the beginning, which is what you're trying to avoid.

In short, no, it's not possible to do with JavaScript. You're left with using CSS.